# negative infinity when using JAVA Math library

Tags: java, math

I know that when a variable is positive zero or negative zero then the result of `Math.log()` would be negative infinity. Now my question is why this code returns negative infinity?!

```
System.out.println((0.5 / Math.log(3600)* Math.log(9 / 60)+ 0.5);
```

but when I using

```
System.out.println((0.5 / Math.log(3600)* Math.log(0.15)+ 0.5);
```

The answer is correct. What caused this problem and how can I fix that?!

Comment: `System.out.println(9/60);`

Comment: Returns 0 value!! why?!!!

Comment: int divided by int, try making 9.0/60 and it should work

Comment: Because `int / int` in Java does integer division ([JLS §15.17 "Multiplicative operators"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)), not floating point.  At least one of the arguments has to be a `float` or `double` to make it do FP division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.log(9 / 60) equals Math.log(0), which is -Infinity.

You can try Math.log(9.0/60) instead.

Comment: How that could be changed to the actual double value of 9/60?

Comment: you should use 9.0 / 60

Comment: Explain about operator overloading, and arithmetic promotion. All of these things apply here, and are vital to a full and valid answer.